# How to render React Child Components from a function call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render, react-component

I'm trying to call a function, rows(), in my App component, which will render PhoneBook child components:

```
import React from 'react';
import PhoneBook from './components/PhoneBook';

const App = () => {
  const rows = () => {
    personsToShow.map(person => 
      <PhoneBook key={personsToShow.length+1} name={person.name} number={person.number}/>
    );
  }

  return (     
    <div>
      {rows()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Where personsToShow is an array consisting of:

```
0: {name: "Arto Hellas", number: "000-000-0000"}
1: {name: "Ada Lovelace", number: "39-44-5323523"}
2: {name: "Dan Abramov", number: "12-43-234345"}
3: {name: "Mary Poppendieck", number: "39-23-6423122"}
```

The PhoneBook child component is defined as:

```
import React from 'react';

const PhoneBook = ({name, number}) => {
    return (
        <div>{name} {number}</div>
    );
}

export default PhoneBook;
```

How come the PhoneBook child components do not get rendered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just forgot to return from your function,

```
const rows = () => {
  //return here
  return personsToShow.map(person => 
    <PhoneBook key={person.number} name={person.name} number={person.number}/>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fhp1pe)

**Note:** You should provide the unique `key`. Your key is not unique here, you can use number (mostly unique) for your key as `key={person.number}`.

Comment: I did not realize I had to return from a function if the function rendered Child components, which have returns on their own.

Answer (score 2):

Omit `{}` in the arrow function to return the expression.

```js
  const rows = () =>
    personsToShow.map(person => 
      <PhoneBook key={personsToShow.length+1} name={person.name} number={person.number}/>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use fuction, use variable, because anonymous functions will get created on every re-render

```
import React from 'react';
import PhoneBook from './components/PhoneBook';

const App = () => {
  const rows = personsToShow.map((person, index) => // removeed function
     <PhoneBook key={index} name={person.name} number={person.number}/>
     //__________^ use proper key
  );


  return (     
    <div>
      {rows} // removed function call
    </div>
  )
}
```